# Group id not shown when view is empty in Drupal 8?

Tags: views, group

I am new to Drupal 8. I make custom view field (programmatically) and pass session variable to it.Session variable contain group id.
The problem is that when the view is empty i mean no content in view then the group id not shown.When the view is not empty the group id shown.check out below code.

logged_in.views.inc

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains logged_in\logged_in.views.inc..
 * Provide a custom views field data that isn't tied to any other module. */

use Drupal\Component\Utility\NestedArray;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;
use Drupal\field\FieldConfigInterface;
use Drupal\field\FieldStorageConfigInterface;
use Drupal\system\ActionConfigEntityInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_views_data().
 */
function logged_in_views_data() {

  $data['views']['table']['group'] = t('Custom Global');
  $data['views']['table']['join'] = [
    // #global is a special flag which allows a table to appear all the time.
    '#global' => [],
  ];


  $data['views']['logged_in'] = [
    'title' => t('Logged in'),
    'help' => t('Checks if a user is logged in.'),
    'field' => [
      'id' => 'logged_in',
    ],
  ];

  return $data;
}


<?php

namespace Drupal\logged_in\Plugin\views\field;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\FieldPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\ResultRow;

/**
 * A handler to provide a field that is completely custom by the administrator.
 *
 * @ingroup views_field_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsField("logged_in")
 */
class LoggedIn extends FieldPluginBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function usesGroupBy() {
    return FALSE;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function query() {
    // Do nothing -- to override the parent query.
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function defineOptions() {
    $options = parent::defineOptions();

    $options['hide_alter_empty'] = ['default' => FALSE];
    return $options;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildOptionsForm(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::buildOptionsForm($form, $form_state);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function render(ResultRow $values) {
    // Return a random text, here you can include your custom logic.
    // Include any namespace required to call the method required to generate
    // the desired output.
     //    $logged_in = \Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated();
    // $logged_in = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
       $logged_in = (int)$_SESSION['groupbysession']['group_id'];
        return $logged_in;
  }
```

}
[image]

```
<div class="all-content-heading"><span><h3>All Session</h3></span></div>
<div class="all-content-button"><span><a class="pull-right " href="group/{{ logged_in | striptags | spaceless }}/content/create/group_node%3Asessions">Add Session</a></span></div>
```

Comment: In these settings. at the very top, did you check the `Display even if view has no result` box?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes the box is checked.But this box is  for header. if view has no content also show the header.

Comment: In the main Views settings, below FOOTER, there is `NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR` add text area here.

Comment: I was also tried this but the same problem.it also doesn't show me group id in path.

Comment: You'll need to pass the variable programmatically directly to the "no results behaviour" instead of using a `{{ logged_in }}` token.

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving me  precious time.I solved it with other way.i make custom token and pass it session varaiable.Now it's working fine.Thanks